# Put strings together in aspx file

Tags: asp.net

I have this code

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ddd" Text='<a href="Agreement.aspx">Accept terms</a> runat="server">
```

This adds a link on "Accept terms". But I only want the link to be on the word "terms". I have tried different stuff, but none works. Most of the examples I found on the internet, were where the strings where pulled up from the database, and were not static. That didnt work. Basically I want this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ddd" Text='Accept' + '<a href="Agreement.aspx">terms</a> runat="server">
```

### Notice the Accept + terms.

Another struggle I have, is that this same code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ddd" Text='<a href="Agreement.aspx">Accept terms</a> runat="server">
```

makes the checkbox and text "Accept terms" be on 2 lines, but I want them on one line.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I solved the first problem. I just had to add the Accept outside the href, which is very obvious, and I tried this before, but got compile errors. I guess it was something else causing the error. 

But I still have not solved the 2nd error, where I want the checkbox and button to be on same line

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ddd" Text='Accept <a href="Agreement.aspx">terms</a>' 
  runat="server"/>
```

You missed a `'` at the end of you `Text` attribute. I've also moved the anchor to `term` as it seems that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ddd" Text='Accept <a href="Agreement.aspx">terms</a>' runat="server" />
```

This should work just tested it.